# Magento - Show magento navigation without any categories

Tags: css, magento

I need to show the navigation with ANY categories. This magento site will not have any products, only html web pages. Maybe if I make a category and hide it somehow.. It only seems to show the navigation if I have a category.. help

Comment: What exactly do you want to show on the navigation other than categories? It seems it is meant to display categories only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change top navigation of Magento site, you should look at this template: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml

Comment: Right, how do I manipulate that top.phtml (or other) page to show the navigation WITHOUT any catagories or products?